# Infinite-valued random variable with finite expectation

Tags: probability

I understand that there are random variables with exclusively finite values and infinite expectation (like the St. Petersburg paradox), but does there exist a random variable that equals $\infty$ somewhere yet has expectation $< \infty$?

Comment: Would a symmetric distribution do the trick? (ie p(x) =p(-x) ergo expectation is 0) you would need to define infinite via limits.

Comment: A random variable cannot _equal_ $\infty$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Why not???

Comment: @copper.hat: Well, perhaps it would be more accurate to say that a random variable on the ordinary reals can't equal $\infty$.

Comment: OP: If the random variable takes on values on the extended reals, it can't equal $\infty$ on a set of positive measure; otherwise, the expectation is infinite or undefined.  I can't think of an interesting example.

Comment: I added a standard example below.

Comment: OP: Informally we don't care about the behaviour of a random variable on a set o measure zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of fair coin tosses until the first head appears. Then $X(TTT\cdots) = \infty$, but $EX = 2 < \infty$.

Comment: Is $\infty$ a number of coin tosses?

Comment: It is the number of coin tosses (less one :-)) that happen before a head appears. The all tails sequence is unlikely but possible.

Comment: But how do we _tell_ that the all-tails sequence has occurred? In the usual sense of probability, wouldn't we just say that $P(X>n)$ decreases with increasing $n$ and then claim that since probability is a set-continuous function, the limit of the probability is the probability of the limit?

Comment: Well, the $\sigma$-field and measureable functions defined on $\Omega$ are somewhat 'independent' (bad word in context) of the probability measure imposed. So, I can define $X$ above on the sequences $\{T,H\}^\mathbb{N}$ without having to concern myself with a probabilty. And it is clear that $T\cdots$ is an element of this set. Stopping times are another example but more complicated to setup up an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. By a random variable $X$, we mean a $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}([-\infty, \infty])$-measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow[-\infty, \infty]$. It may happen that $X$ takes value $\infty$ but $\{\omega \mid X(\omega)=\infty\}$ has measure zero. In this case, $X$ may still be integrable. (i.e., has a finite expectation)

Note that, in many textbooks, the authors restrict the co-domain of $X$ to be $\mathbb{R}$. That is, the word "random variable" is reserved for a $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. They use the word "random map" to mean $X:\Omega\rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$.